# Display hashed commands for your current shell session

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-16.04

Display hashed commands for your current shell session By shell script file extension .sh

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a script in your current shell, you can use `source` shell builtin command.

So if your script contains a `hash` command and you run your script like:

```
source script.sh
```

It will show hashed commands for your current shell.

Comment: Inside Script File 
#!/bin/bash
# Show hash command on Ternimal

echo $hash


Wrtie on Terminal
./script.sh


No output

Comment: `echo $hash` in your script will output contents of variable called `hash` - is that what you want? Or you want the same output as if you typed `hash` into your terminal?

Comment: last answered is use full thanks. echo $hash worked in terminal  and just hash worked in script.sh file